# Latex equations when uploading a markdown script to wordpress via knit2wp()

Tags: r, wordpress, latex, markdown, knitr

I got a problem. I successfully upload an markdown script to wordpress.com via the knit2wp() function. knit2wp() translates the LAtex equations to mathjax I guess. And therefore it doest display the formulas in the blog.

Is there any workaround so the Latex equations dont get translated?
This is the standard code from the knitr homepage for uploading a new post:

```
if (!require('RWordPress'))
    install.packages('RWordPress', repos = 'http://www.omegahat.org/R', type = 'source')
library(RWordPress)
options(WordpressLogin = c(pozelei = '*********'),
    WordpressURL = 'http://pozelei.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php')
library(knitr)

knit2wp('gibbs_post.Rmd', title = 'Gibbs sampling with Rcpp - Speed up your      code!2',shortcode=c(1,1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to [load MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html) in your WordPress site. You are recommended to do this through a plugin, or modify your theme if you have write access to it. If you are unable to do either, you may have to manually load it in each single post:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Comment: @MartinDabbelJuSmelter Well, WordPress.com does not allow `<script>` in blog posts, so you are out of luck. Setting up a private WordPress blog site is not too expensive. Jekyll+Github is another option that gives you freedom.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers).

Comment: I installed and activated the Mathjax-Latex add-on for my wordpress.org site. Once I checked the "Force Load" box in the settings, it worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, wordpress.com does not allow users to load MathJax.

You can use the TeX2PNG rendering that's available, see http://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/. You'll probably have to modify the math delimiters to `$latex ... $` (there's no display mode).